MUI Datagrid with PaginationMode = "server" and autoPageSize = true to automatically calculate pageSize
I am trying to utilize autpPageSize with paginationMode={"server"}
I am expecting the autoPageSize to determine the pageSize available for the space and the hasNextPage to make the next page button go away.
It seems that the next page button does not disappear.
Am I do this correctly?
export function Alerts() {
const [dataRows, setDataRows] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(null);
const [token, setToken] = useState(null);


const [paginationMeta, setPagnationMeta] = useState({hasNextPage:true});

const fetchTriggers = async (limitSize, nextToken) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const client = generateClient();
    try {
        const { data } = await client.graphql({
            query: listTriggers,
            variables: {
                limit: limitSize,
                nextToken: nextToken,
                }
            },
        });
        setDataRows(data.listTriggers.items);
        setToken(data.listTriggers.nextToken);
       setPagnationMeta({hasNextPage:data.listTriggers.nextToken !== null});
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
    }
};

const onPaginationModelChange = async (newModel) => {
        console.log(newModel);
        if (pageSize === null){
            setPageSize(newModel.pageSize)
            fetchTriggers(newModel.pageSize, token)
        }else {

            fetchTriggers(pageSize, token)
        } 
    };

return (
        <DataGridPro
            rows={dataRows}
            loading={isLoading}
            disableSelectionOnClick
            autoPageSize
            rowCount={-1}
            pagination
            paginationMode={"server"}
            paginationMeta={paginationMeta}
            onPaginationModelChange={onPaginationModelChange}
        />
);

}
